# Anyway to save a parameter inside a function until it is replaced by calling the same function with new parameter?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function name myFunA, when the first time call the function and pass a parameter to it, the function actually stored the variable. Each time I call this function, it will return the same variable, until I call the function again and pass a parameter to replace the previous parameter.

```
function myFunA(input){
 if(input exist){
  storedVar = input //declare a variable and store the input
 }
 console.log(storedVar);
}

myFunA('First Input'); // output will be 'First Input'.
myFunA(); // output will still be 'First Input'.
myFunA('Second Input'); // output will be 'Second Input'.
myFunA(); // As the variable is replaced, the output will still be 'Second Input'.
```

Is this possible?

I know that there is a Garbage Collection feature in JavaScript to scrap the variable and release memory, but is there anyway to prevent?

Really appreciate if someone could let me know the way. If this is not possible to achieve, it is still good to confirm it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your code does print the values you wanted if u replace if(input exist) with if(input) !

Comment: Well, you are right if the first call alway provide a parameter.

However, if the first call provide nothing, then it will return error. So it is kind of incomplete I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript functions are [first class objects](http://helephant.com/2008/08/19/functions-are-first-class-objects-in-javascript/). Therefore, you can set a property of the function just like any other variable.

```
function myFunA(input) {
    if (input) {
        myFunA.storedVar = input;
    }
    console.log(myFunA.storedVar);
}

myFunA('First Input');  // First Input
myFunA();               // First Input
myFunA('Second Input'); // Second Input
myFunA();               // Second Input
```

Comment: Huh. I've never seen that before.

Comment: Oh... Well, this is great. Never think of achieving it this way.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @NinaScholz is fine, but allows you to change the stored value without calling the function. If you want to avoid it, here is another pattern :

```
var myFunA = (function() {
    var storedVar = null;
    return function(input) {
        if(typeof(input) != "undefined") {
            storedVar = input;
        }
        console.log(storedVar);
    };
})();
```

Comment: That's true, and your function could store empty string too, which is great. 

Though I will use Nina's solution this time, since it is enough already. I will note down yours for future use.

Thank you very much :).